# Get the button that caused the submit from the form submit event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, webforms

I'm trying to find the value of the submit button that triggered the form to submit, so in accordance I can do differents things, actually I use this:

```js
$("#regform").on('submit', function(e) {
  if (($(document.activeElement).val()) == "cf") {
    e.preventDefault();
    // This doesnt work on iOs Devices
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="action.php" method="post" id="regform" class="regform" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit" id="check-cf" value="cf">Check CF</button>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" value="Reg">
</form>
```

`document.activeElement` doesn't work in many cases. What should I use nowadays to be compatible to achieve that?

Comment: $("input:focus").dowhatever();

Comment: What exactly are you expecting the `dowhatever()` part to 1) actually be in reality, and 2) achieve?

Comment: or `if ( $("#check-cf").is(":focus") ) { }`

Comment: To answer the question in the title, you can retrieve `event.submitter`. It returns an element triggered the submission, or `null` if the submission was triggered by hitting ENTER on an input. With jQuery events you've to check `event.originalEvent.submitter`, as jQuery's event object doesn't contain the said property.

Comment: A small corrective to the previous comment, when hitting ENTER on an input, `null` is returned only, if there's no actual submit button in the form, otherwise that button is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the `value="cf"` button a `type="button"` element. Then you don't need any JS code to prevent the form submission at all.

```html
<form action="action.php" method="post" id="regform" class="regform" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="check-cf" value="cf">Check CF</button>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" value="Reg">
</form>
```

If, for whatever reason, you can't do that then you will need to hook to the `click` events of the submit buttons in the form, detect their `value`, and prevent the form submission from there:

```js
$('form :submit').on('click', function(e) {
  if ($(this).val() == "cf") {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('form submission blocked...');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="action.php" method="post" id="regform" class="regform" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit" id="check-cf" value="cf">Check CF</button>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" value="Reg">
</form>
```

Comment: The second solution work perfect, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

there two way to do it as I see it

```
$("#regform").on('submit', function(e) {
   if ( $("#check-cf").is(":focus") ) {
     alert( 'check-cf clicked');
  }
  else {
    alert( 'Reg clicked');
  }
  $("#regform").submit()   or return false;  // if you dont want to submit it
});
```

or

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn", function() {
   if ( $(this).val() == 'cf' ) {
      alert( 'check-cf clicked');
  }
  else {
     alert( 'Reg clicked');
  }
  $("#regform").submit()   or return false;  // if you dont want to submit it
})
```

Comment: The first solution still isn't working on iOs

Comment: and what about the second then?